# When would I ever need to use ".noData" when calling the complete function on background fetch?

Tags: ios, swift

If you have set up a background fetch task to run on iOS, after it completes, you're required to call `completionHandler` with one of three options: `.newData`, `.noData` or `.failed`. Depending on which one you pick and how your tasks succeed, apparently iOS decides how often your app's background fetch is run.

`.newData` is the obvious default if everything went fine and `.failed` is the obvious fail option, but what about `.noData`? If iOS penalizes me for attempting to fetch data that is stale, why would I ever want to tell iOS about this? If this affects the frequency of the background job, wouldn't I be better off just always telling iOS that all data I fetched was new to avoid my app being forced to run background jobs less often than what I defined in `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval`?

Comment: I don't think there is any connection between status type used and any up- or down prioritizing of your download tasks. If you need to download so much data it can't be handled in a single 30 second slot then isn't the pattern to use to return .newData for each task until you are done and then return .noData?

Comment: You should be a "good citizen". If you have no new data, let iOS know. It will analyse your completion values to try and identify when is a good time to perform a background fetch; e.g. if there is always new data at 5 pm and never new data at 9 am it is more likely to call you in the afternoon. What is the point in running more frequently if you have no data to fetch? You are just impacting battery and network for no reason.

Comment: @Paulw11 In my case I know that there is no pattern to when new data is available, but I know that I want to check for new data every 2 hours. Just because there has been data at 5pm for three weeks in a row, is not a guarantee that there is new data at that time in the future. I would like to be able to decide this and I'm worried that iOS is making false assumptions about new data availability if I tell anything to it.

Comment: It is more likely to penalise you if you always return .newData when there isn’t much data transfer

Comment: @Paulw11 That's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

> Depending on which one you pick and how your tasks succeed, apparently iOS decides how often your app's background fetch is run.

That’s a false assumption. What is evaluated is the time and energy you use before calling the completion handler. Do not try to game the system; just be quick, efficient, and honest.

Comment: My assumption may be wrong, but based on the vague wording on Apple Docs I'm not convinced it is. If only time and energy is evaluated, then I should definitely be honest and just tell iOS the truth. If however I think I know better than the system how often the calls should be made, I might be incentivized to lie to avoid being penalized. I'm mostly questioning the validity of a system that encourages developers to lie to rationally pursue their goals.